# Why the Network in Chrome Developer Tool is not showing the actual product image size?

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.3

We have the image resolution for product images as below:

- For Single page - 960x1200
- For Double page - 1920x1200

But when I check the Network in Chrome developer tool, it's showing the product image dimension as 560x700.

Why the Image dimension showing differently in Chrome developer tool? Is this something related to the theme?

Please reply with your thoughts.